# Emacs: Don't create #these# files when not saving modified buffer

Tags: emacs, autosave

How do I prevent Emacs from creating backup copies of buffers I don't wish to save when I kill buffers that have not been saved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [Here](http://www.rensselaer.org/dept/acs/rpinfo/common/Computing/Consulting/Software/Emacs/Hints/backup.html)

Short version: put

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

in you .emacs file, or toggle this feature at any time with `M-x auto-save-mode`.

Here is the [Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Control.html) Node.

Comment: Links are OK, but it is better to copy the actual soution into StackOverflow then to count on it remaining indefinitly somewhere out on the web...

Comment: Thank you for editing. I have to admit I rushed it. If you look in the revision, I did post an example but was not in the situation to test it. So I removed it.

Comment: I should point out that the OP asked how to disable `auto-save`, not how to disable `backup-files`, as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want emacs to litter your drive with backup files try adding the following to your .emacs file:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/emacs-backups")))
```

This will store every backup in a single location.

Comment: I'm not sure tat this really answers the question, but I like it.

Comment: You're right, I just assumed the reason that skurpur wanted to disable  backups was because of all those messy droppings that Emacs leaves behind. Setting the backup-directory-alist variable is just a simple way of house training it.

Answer (score 2):

I would advice you to use something like:

```
(defvar backup-dir "~/.emacs.d/backups/")
(setq backup-directory-alist (list (cons "." backup-dir)))
```

This way you can have all backup files in one directory.