# How can I hide the backup files that emacs creates?

Tags: emacs

I just started using emacs after having used vi for a long time. :)

One thing which is annoying me is that whenever I modify a file, save it and exit emacs, I see a backup file created in the same directory named `filename~` (if the file I edited was `filename`).

Is there any way I can get rid of this? Or hide these files? It is *very* annoying to see tons of backup files when I do ls of the directory.

Comment: Those would be what we usually call 'backup files'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can either move them to their own folder with the following code:

```
;; Don't clutter up directories with files~
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,(expand-file-name
                                    (concat dotfiles-dir "backups")))))

;; Don't clutter with #files either
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,(expand-file-name (concat dotfiles-dir "backups")))))
```

Or you can remove them completely, like so:

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)
(setq auto-save-default nil)
```

Personally I would be wary of removing them as they can come in useful. Further discussion is here:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupDirectory
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave

I would recommend checking out the **emacs-starter-kit** it sorts out a load of issues that people have when coming to emacs, and is pretty heavily used.

http://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit/blob/master/starter-kit-misc.el

---

Update:

There seems to be much confusion over how to use the functions. I'm going to have a little play around later but here is some more information. Note that `auto-save-file-name-transforms`:

> lets you specify a series of regular expressions and replacements to transform the auto save file name
>   [[emacs-manual]](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Files.html)

so it's not just as simple as adding in a folder name. That said it seems from a quick google search the following might just do what you all want:

```
;;; backup/autosave
(defvar backup-dir (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/backup/"))
(defvar autosave-dir (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/autosave/"))
(setq backup-directory-alist (list (cons ".*" backup-dir)))
(setq auto-save-list-file-prefix autosave-dir)
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*" ,autosave-dir t)))
```

http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=auto-save-file-name-transforms&sbtn=Search

Comment: Thanks! Is there something similar for the files created with name #filename#?

Comment: When I use this, I get, "Symbol's value as variable is void: dotfiles-dir"

Comment: the code is taken from the github link. to get it to work you need to replace the `(expand-file-name (concat dotfiles-dir "backups"))` part with whatever folder you want your files to go into. if you need more help try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199216/emacs-dont-create-these-files-when-not-saving-modified-buffer/1199335#1199335

Comment: So, I added this to my emacs file:
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*" ,"~/.emacs-backups/")))

But emacs is creating files with name "##" in the specified directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Awesome! The code in your update works perfectly! Thanks a lot James.

Answer (score 5):

The following lines in `~/.emacs` will put all of the auto-save and backup files in `/tmp`:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory)))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
```

Comment: It looks like the good solution for me. It's the one I used. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

In your .emacs:

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

Edit:
If you're unfamiliar with the .emacs file, it's a file named `.emacs` that resides in your user $HOME directory. If you don't have one already, you can just create it and emacs will load it on startup.

Comment: Thanks! Is there something similar for the files created with name #filename#?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one. To be honest, I'd hesitate to remove them completely, because usually that means emacs was closed without saving a buffer. I usually save frequently, so if a #file# does exist, it means emacs/the machine crashed; I usually end up using it to recover a file.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link](https://superuser.com/questions/84164/how-do-i-stop-emacs-from-creating-backup-files) to the same question answered on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) and [my response](https://superuser.com/questions/84164/how-do-i-stop-emacs-from-creating-backup-files/91301#91301). And a StackOverflow question entitled [Emacs: Don’t create #these# files when not saving modified buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199216/emacs-dont-create-these-files-when-not-saving-modified-buffer)

And for completeness, as stated by others; to stop the backup files being created put this in your `.emacs`

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```