# Emacs auto-save: Why are files not stored in the correct folder?

Tags: emacs, autosave

I looked in various places and finally came up with the following setup for 'auto-save' mode in Emacs:

```
(defvar my-auto-save-folder (concat "~/.emacs.d/auto-save")); folder for auto-saves
(setq auto-save-list-file-prefix "~/.emacs.d/auto-save/.saves-"); set prefix for auto-saves 
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*", my-auto-save-folder t))); location for all auto-save files
(setq tramp-auto-save-directory my-auto-save-folder); auto-save tramp files in local directory
```

After having this setup for some weeks, I visited ~/.emacs.d and found that the folder ~/.emacs.d/auto-save is empty, while ~/.emacs.d contained two auto-save files of the form `#!home!<myusername>!<myfolder>!<myfile>`. Why are the auto-save files not stored in ~/.emacs.d/auto-save? [the folder `auto-save` has rights 775, `.emacs.d` 700]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is in:

```
(defvar my-auto-save-folder (concat "~/.emacs.d/auto-save")); folder for auto-saves
```

(the call to `concat` with a single argument is pointless, incidentally).

> If the optional element UNIQUIFY is non-nil, the auto-save file name is
>   constructed by taking **the directory part of the replaced file-name**,
>   concatenated with the buffer file name with all directory separators
>   changed to `!' to prevent clashes.

Emacs identifies directory names by a trailing `/`, which means that "the directory part" of the path you've used is "~/.emacs.d/".

You want:

```
(defvar my-auto-save-folder "~/.emacs.d/auto-save/"); folder for auto-saves
```

The positioning of the comma in the following is also strange (although apparently it still works):

```
`((".*", my-auto-save-folder t)))
```

That should really be:

```
`((".*" ,my-auto-save-folder t)))
```

Comment: Hi phils, thanks for helping. Why is the placement of the comma important (or rather: why should it be as you pointed out)?

Comment: Marius: Read this: `C-h i g (elisp) Backquote RET`. The comma says to evaluate `my-auto-save-folder`, so it is associated with that element of the list, rather than the previous `".*"` element (in which position it appears more like an accidental attempt to use comma-separated values in a lisp list!).

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have in my .emacs, which works well for me:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-save-file-name-transforms
             (list "\\(.+/\\)*\\(.*?\\)" (expand-file-name "\\2" my-auto-save-folder))
             t)
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a bit more details what the code does. I found something similar here (http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2003-09/msg00022.html) but it's not exactly the same. I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020941/emacs-newbie-how-can-i-hide-the-buffer-files-that-emacs-creates which uses `expand-file-name` instead of `concat`.

Comment: jtahlborn: That looks a bit odd. Setting the `UNIQUIFY` argument (`t`) means only the directory part of the replaced name is used, so there's no point in substituting the 2nd group into that path (although as your second group is non-greedy, I don't think it is ever going to contain anything).

Comment: @phils - i'm not setting the uniquify argument, that is the last param to add-to-list.  and it works great.

Comment: jtahlborn: My apologies; I misread that badly. I'm genuinely confused about the non-greedy match, though. After the `string-match` call, `(match-string 2 string)` is definitely an empty string, but I can also see that the `replace-match` call does appear to replace the `\2` with the filename. Ah, but of course it's only replacing within the portion of the string that was *matched* by the regexp (which *excludes* the filename), so in fact it's replacing `\2` with the empty string after all. That explains it!